# Setting variable through external method in method of object

Tags: javascript, object, methods

I am using the method of a javascript object to create HTML to write that object. 
Within that method I have a date (in string format as a SQL Date) which I format to dd MMM YYYY in an external method. The external method works fine returning the string I need, but when I set the variable within my object's method it is returned as `undefined`.

Hereby the relevant code:

```
function CreateReview(reviewID, visitDate) {
    var reviewObject = {
        iD: reviewID,
        visitDate: visitDate, 
        CreateReviewObject : function(c) {
            var reviewContainer = document.createElement('div');
            reviewContainer.id = 'Review_' + this.iD;
            reviewContainer.className  = 'Card Review';
            var headerDIV = document.createElement('div');
            headerDIV.className  = 'Header';
            var dateTagsDIV = document.createElement('div');
            dateTagsDIV.className  = 'DateTags';
            var datesDIV = document.createElement('div');
            datesDIV.className  = 'Dates';
            var formattedVisitDate = getFormattedDate(this.visitDate);
            console.log(formattedVisitDate);
            var dateDIV = document.createElement('div');
            dateDIV.className  = 'Date';
            dateDIV.innerHTML = formattedVisitDate;
            datesDIV.appendChild(dateDIV);
            dateTagsDIV.appendChild(datesDIV);
            headerDIV.appendChild(dateTagsDIV);
            reviewContainer.appendChild(headerDIV);

            return reviewContainer;
        }
    };

    return reviewObject;
}

function getFormattedDate(input) {
    input = input.replace(/-/g,'/');
    var pattern = /(.*?)\/(.*?)\/(.*?)$/;
    var result = input.replace(pattern,function(match,p1,p2,p3){
        p2 = parseInt(p2);
        p3 = parseInt(p3);
        var months = ['jan','feb','maa','apr','mei','jun','jul','aug','sep','okt','nov','dec'];
        var date = (p3<10?"0"+p3:p3) + " " + months[parseInt(p2-1)] + " " + p1;
        console.log(date);
        return date;

    });
}
```

The output of the console in `getFormattedDate` is then

```
12 mei 2015
```

While in `CreateReview` it is

```
undefined
```

I have tried the following way as well:

```
function CreateReview(reviewID, restaurant, kitchenTypes, tags, pictures, ratings, thumbPicture, visitDate, introduction, description) {
    var reviewObject = {
        iD: reviewID,
        visitDate: visitDate, 
        CreateReviewObject : function(c) {
            var getFormattedVisitDate = function(visitDate) {
              return function() { getFormattedDate(visitDate); };
            };
            var reviewContainer = document.createElement('div');
            reviewContainer.id = 'Review_' + this.iD;
            reviewContainer.className  = 'Card Review';
            var headerDIV = document.createElement('div');
            headerDIV.className  = 'Header';
            var dateTagsDIV = document.createElement('div');
            dateTagsDIV.className  = 'DateTags';
            var datesDIV = document.createElement('div');
            datesDIV.className  = 'Dates';
            var formattedVisitDate = getFormattedVisitDate(this.visitDate);
            console.log(formattedVisitDate);
            var dateDIV = document.createElement('div');
            dateDIV.className  = 'Date';
            dateDIV.innerHTML = formattedVisitDate;
            datesDIV.appendChild(dateDIV);
            dateTagsDIV.appendChild(datesDIV);
            headerDIV.appendChild(dateTagsDIV);
            reviewContainer.appendChild(headerDIV);

            return reviewContainer;
        }
    };

    return reviewObject;
}

function getFormattedDate(input) {
    input = input.replace(/-/g,'/');
    var pattern = /(.*?)\/(.*?)\/(.*?)$/;
    var result = input.replace(pattern,function(match,p1,p2,p3){
        p2 = parseInt(p2);
        p3 = parseInt(p3);
        var months = ['jan','feb','maa','apr','mei','jun','jul','aug','sep','okt','nov','dec'];
        var date = (p3<10?"0"+p3:p3) + " " + months[parseInt(p2-1)] + " " + p1;
        console.log(date);
        return date;

    });
}
```

Which gives me this output in  in `CreateReview`:

```
return function() { getFormattedDate(visitDate); };
```

Why does the `CreateReview` call return `undefined` when the console does not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `function getFormattedDate()`, you have

```
var result = input.replace(pattern, function(match,p1,p2,p3) {... return date; });
```

so `result` contains the returned value of the `replace` function, but `getFormattedDate` doesn't return anything ==> undefined when called from `CreateReview`.

Add `return result;` at the end of the function `getFormattedDate`.